# How to disable OpenCL with wand in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagemagick, opencl, wand

So I'm using wand for a project and it's been working fine, except whenever I want to use a function that has been 'OpenCL-accelerated' (list of functions [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/opencl.php)), it stops working, no error or anything, but I'm pretty sure that OpenCL is what's causing it.

So my question is, **how can I disable OpenCL in wand so that I can use those functions?** Again, I've looked for solutions, but alas I couldn't find anything python specific, and the api module and the python module itself don't seem to mention anything about it either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If any more information is required please just ask!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the environment variable `MAGICK_OCL_DEVICE=off` to disable OpenCL.

Either before running the script.

```sh
export MAGICK_OCL_DEVICE=OFF
python myScript.py
```

Or within the python script **before** invoking any Wand code.

```py
 import os

 os.environ['MAGICK_OCL_DEVICE'] = 'OFF'

 # ... wand stuff ...
```

And the reason that it looks like your application stops running is that ImageMagick will need to run an OpenCL benchmark the first time and that can take a while. The result of the benchmark will be cached and used the next time an "OpenCL-accelerated" method is executed.